# Why is the last object in the array showing up?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass info across views, which works, but the program does not pick up the right information. I have buttons in an array, in this case 3 buttons, and when I click that button I want the buttons information i.e. the image to be transferred to the next view. The problem is that no matter which button I click the last button of the array will always transfer its data to the next view. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
  var userbutton = [UIButton]()

   var userbutton = UIButton()
        userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
        userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
        userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)


 func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){

    for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate(){
    self.dicSelected = ["text" : usernamearray[index] , "image" :  upimage[index]]
    print(dicSelected)

    self.selectedData.text = usernamearray[index] as? String
    self.selectedData.image = upimage[index] as? UIImage

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nearmeprofile", sender: self)
    }
}
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "nearmeprofile"){              
        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! NearMeProfile
        nextViewOBJ.neardataModel = self.selectedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a repeat loop in the method `buttonAction` which writes the data always into the same variables. Therefore the variables contain the data of the last iteration.

Comment: How would I fix the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you going to accomplish?

Comment: I have these three images, when one of them is clicked, then that picture will be passed on to the next view controller. http://puu.sh/lTL0X/1ed55f5a28.png

Comment: i think i gave answer to your problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259559/why-is-the-sender-tag-always-zero/34259673#34259673

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send image/text 1 when clicking button 1 ... image / text 3 when clicking button 3 than the easiest way is to assign tags to the buttons and connect all of them to the same action.

For example assign tag 100 to the first button, 101 to the second and 102 to the third button. I prefer not to start with 0 because all UI elements have a tag 0 by default. Then connect all buttons to the action

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

   let index = sender.tag - 100 // remove the offset of 100    
   self.dicSelected = ["text" : usernamearray[index] , "image" :  upimage[index]]
   print(dicSelected)

   self.selectedData.text = usernamearray[index] as? String
   self.selectedData.image = upimage[index] as? UIImage

  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nearmeprofile", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: When I click any button other than the first one, it registers as the first index.

Comment: When I print the sender.tag it is always zero. The button action is through an array of buttons I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

You asked same question with different method.But answer is same..

```
var userbutton = [UIButton]()
var upimage = [UIImage]()
var usernamearray = [String]()

for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate(){

        var userbutton = UIButton()
        userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
        userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
        userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)
        userbutton.tag = index  // <-- ADD this Line in your code.
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   let index = sender.tag
      self.dicSelected = ["text" : usernamearray[index] , "image" :  upimage[index]]

   print("index\(index)")

    self.selectedData.text = usernamearray[index] as? String
    self.selectedData.image = upimage[index] as? UIImage

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nearmeprofile", sender: dicSelected)

}
```