# Why is the sender.tag always zero?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of buttons and when I add the action the sender.tag is always zero. How do I fix this? Below is my attempt to do this. When a button is clicked I am trying to get the image and name in another array to pass to the next view controller. The problem is that the `sender.tag` is always zero.

```
var userbutton = [UIButton]()
var upimage = [UIImage]()
var usernamearray = [String]()

for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate(){

        var userbutton = UIButton()
        userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
        userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
        userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
        userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   let index = sender.tag
      self.dicSelected = ["text" : usernamearray[index] , "image" :  upimage[index]]

   print("index\(index)")

    self.selectedData.text = usernamearray[index] as? String
    self.selectedData.image = upimage[index] as? UIImage

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nearmeprofile", sender: dicSelected)

}
```

Comment: You need to set your button tag value programmatically or using Xcode IB

Comment: What do you mean set it programmatically how would I do that?

Comment: just set a value -> sender.tag = 1

Comment: Why do you expect a non-zero tag value? You never set the button's tag to anything.

Comment: I want to know which button is clicked, I have updated my code. When I set the tag to 1 I get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use last line code to get different tag for all your UIButton.

```
for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate(){

    var userbutton = UIButton()
    userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
    userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
    userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
    userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)
    userbutton.tag=index;  // <-- ADD this Line in your code.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this set the first button's tag to `0`? You should never use a tag value of `0` since that is the default for all views.

Comment: If you agree then you might want to update your answer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Like others said, you never set the `tag` property of any of your buttons, so they are all at the default value of `0`.

Try this:

```
let tagBaseValue = 1000 // Custom value

for (index, users) in upimage.enumerate(){

    let tag = tagBaseValue + index

    var userbutton = UIButton()
    userbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    userbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)
    userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = userbutton.frame.size.width/2
    userbutton.clipsToBounds = true
    userbutton.setImage(users, forState: .Normal)

    userButton.tag = tag // <-- ADD THIS LINE!!!
}
```

**EDITED:** Made custom button tags start at a high value, different from zero, in order to distinguish from buttons *without* a custom tag value set (following suggestion by @rmaddy in the comments of @VirajPadsala's answer).